# A n. & s. condition for $Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F = (a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3) (a_4 x + a_5 y + a_6)$ for each $(x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(Note: *n. & s.* is short for *necessary and sufficient*.)

> Suppose that $f(x, y) = Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F$,
> where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$ are six complex numbers.
> Prove or disprove that
> there exist six complex numbers
> $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_6$
> such that
> $$
> Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F = (a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3) (a_4 x + a_5 y + a_6)
> $$
> for each ordered pair of complex numbers $(x, y) \in \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$
> if and only if
> $$
> \det {\begin{bmatrix}
> A & B & D \\
> B & C & E \\
> D & E & F \\
> \end{bmatrix}} = 0.
> $$

The *only if* part is not hard.
Suppose that
$$
Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Dx + 2Ey + F = (a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3) (a_4 x + a_5 y + a_6).
$$
Comparing both sides, we yield
$$
\begin{aligned}
         & A = a_1 a_4, \quad C = a_2 a_5, \quad F = a_3 a_6, \\
         & 2B = a_1 a_5 + a_2 a_4,                            \\
         & 2D = a_1 a_6 + a_3 a_4,                            \\
         & 2E = a_2 a_6 + a_3 a_5.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
        & \det {\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & D \\
B & C & E \\
D & E & F \\
\end{bmatrix}}
\\
        = {} & ACF + BED + DBE - AEE - BBF - DCD
\\
        = {} & ACF + 2BED - (AE^2 + CD^2 + FB^2)                                                                                        \\
        = {} & \frac{1}{4} (4ACF + 2B \cdot 2E \cdot 2D) - \frac{1}{4} (A (2E)^2 + C (2D)^2 + F(2B)^2)                                  \\
        = {} & \frac{1}{4} (4 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_5 a_6 + a_2 a_3^2 a_5 a_4^2+a_2^2 a_3 a_6 a_4^2+a_1 a_3^2 a_5^2 a_4+a_1 a_2^2 a_6^2 a_4 \\
             & \quad \quad +2 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_5 a_6 a_4+a_1^2 a_2 a_5 a_6^2+a_1^2 a_3 a_5^2 a_6)                                          \\
             & \quad - \frac{1}{4} (a_1 a_3^2 a_4 a_5^2+2 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 a_6 a_5+a_1 a_2^2 a_4 a_6^2                                   \\
             & \quad \quad +a_2 a_3^2 a_5 a_4^2+2 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_5 a_6 a_4+a_1^2 a_2 a_5 a_6^2                                           \\
             & \quad \quad +a_2^2 a_3 a_6 a_4^2+2 a_1 a_2 a_3 a_5 a_6 a_4+a_1^2 a_3 a_5^2 a_6)                                          \\
        = {} & 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

However, the *if* part is hard; I do not know what I should do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic

Comment: this is in a book by Schinzel  https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/polynomials-with-special-regard-to-reducibility/FBC37D46462D46A6E121FFC9A09391C5   This is Corollary 2  on page  212

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @AnneBauval. However, I am afraid that I do not really get it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @WillJagy. I did found the corollary that you mentioned, but the book to which you referred seems to be so hard for me that I do not get it, either. To be more specific, I even do not know what most of the terms used by the book mean....

Comment: also here, http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brookfield_Factoring_Forms_2016.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the question.

Here is the *if* part.

---

Suppose that
$$
\Delta = 
\det {
\begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & D \\
    B & C & E \\
    D & E & F \\
\end{bmatrix}
}
= ACF + 2BED - (AE^2 + CD^2 + FB^2) = 0.
$$

The proof splits into a few cases.

(a)
$A = B = C = 0$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y)
    = 2Dx + 2Ey + F
    = (0x + 0y + 1)(2Dx + 2Ey + F).
\end{aligned}
$$

(b)
$A = C = 0$, but $B \neq 0$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y)
    = {} & 2Bxy + 2Dx + 2Ey + F                                                               \\
    = {} & \frac{2}{B}(Bx \cdot By + D \cdot Bx + E \cdot By) + F                             \\
    = {} & \frac{2}{B}(Bx \cdot By + D \cdot Bx + E \cdot By + DE - DE) + F                   \\
    = {} & \frac{2}{B}(Bx \cdot By + D \cdot Bx + E \cdot By + DE) - \frac{2}{B} \cdot DE + F \\
    = {} & \frac{2}{B}(Bx + E)(By + D) - \frac{2ED - FB}{B}                                   \\
    = {} & \left(1x + 0y + \frac{E}{B}\right)(0x + 2By + 2D) - \frac{2BED - FB^2}{B^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\Delta = 0$ and $A = C = 0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \Delta = 0 + 2BED - (0 + 0 + FB^2) = 2BED - FB^2 = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
We conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \left(1x + 0y + \frac{E}{B}\right)(0x + 2By + 2D).
\end{aligned}
$$

(c)
$A \neq 0$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & f(x, y)                                                                                      \\
    = {} & Ax^2 + 2(By + D)x + (Cy^2 + 2Ey + F)                                                         \\
    = {} & \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2 - (By + D)^2}{A}
    + (Cy^2 + 2Ey + F)                                                                                  \\
    = {} & \frac{1}{A} (Ax + By + D)^2 + \frac{1}{A}((AC - B^2)y^2 + 2(AE - BD)y) + \frac{AF - D^2}{A}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The case splits into two subcases.

(c.1)
$AC - B^2 = 0$.
Hence $C = \frac{B^2}{A}$.
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \Delta
    = {} & A \cdot \frac{B^2}{A} \cdot F + 2BED - AE^2
    - \frac{B^2 D^2}{A} - FB^2                         \\
    = {} & {-\frac{1}{A}}
    (A^2 E^2 - 2AE BD + B^2 D^2)                       \\
    = {} & {-\frac{1}{A}} (AE - BD)^2.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\Delta = 0$,
we have $AE - BD = 0$.
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2 - (D^2 - AF)}{A}.
\end{aligned}
$$
There exists a complex number $d$ such that $d^2 = D^2 - AF$.
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \frac{1}{A} (Ax + By + D + d)(Ax + By + D - d),
\end{aligned}
$$
which is
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \left( 1x + \frac{B}{A} y + \frac{D+d}{A} \right) (Ax + By + (D - d)).
\end{aligned}
$$

(c.2)
$AC - B^2 \neq 0$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
            & (AC - B^2) y^2 + 2(AE - BD)y
    \\
    = {} & \frac{1}{AC - B^2} ((AC - B^2)y + (AE - BD))^2 - \frac{(AE - BD)^2}{AC - B^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y)
    = {} & \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2}{A} - \frac{((B^2 - AC)y + (BD - AE))^2}{A(B^2 - AC)}
    \\
            & \quad
    + \frac{AF - D^2}{A} - \frac{(AE - BD)^2}{A(AC - B^2)},
\end{aligned}
$$
which is just
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2}{A} - \frac{((B^2 - AC)y + (BD - AE))^2}{A(B^2 - AC)} + \frac{\Delta}{AC - B^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\Delta = 0$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y) = \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2}{A} - \frac{((B^2 - AC)y + (BD - AE))^2}{A(B^2 - AC)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
There exists a complex number $e$ such that $e^2 = B^2 - AC$.
Put $f = \frac{BD-AE}{e}$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
    f(x, y)
    = {} & \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2}{A} - \frac{(e^2 y + ef)^2}{Ae^2}                   \\
    = {} & \frac{(Ax + By + D)^2}{A} - \frac{(ey + f)^2}{A}                          \\
    = {} & \frac{1}{A}(Ax + By + D + ey + f)(Ax + By + D - ey - f)                   \\
    = {} & \left( 1x + \frac{B+e}{A}y + \frac{D+f}{A} \right) (Ax + (B-e)y + (D-f)).
\end{aligned}
$$

(d)
$C \neq 0$.
We rewrite $f(x, y)$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
    Cy^2 + 2Byx + Ax^2 + 2Ey + 2Dx + F.
\end{aligned}
$$
Put
$$
\begin{aligned}
    g(x, y) = Cx^2 + 2Bxy + Ay^2 + 2Ex + 2Dy + F,
\end{aligned}
$$
which means that for any ordered pair of complex numbers $(z, w)$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
    g(z, w) = f(w, z).
\end{aligned}
$$
A straightforward computation show that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \Delta'
    = {} &
    \det {\begin{bmatrix}
        C & B & E \\
        B & A & D \\
        E & D & F \\
    \end{bmatrix}}                           \\
    = {} & CAF + 2BDE - (CD^2 + AE^2 + FB^2) \\
    = {} & ACF + 2BED - (AE^2 + CD^2 + FB^2) \\
    = {} & \Delta.
\end{aligned}
$$
By (c), there exist six complex numbers
$a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_6$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
    g(x, y) = (a_1 x + a_2 y + a_3) (a_4 x + a_5 y + a_6).
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
        &
    f(x, y) = g(y, x) = (a_2 x + a_1 y + a_3) (a_5 x + a_4 y + a_6).
\end{aligned}
$$